# mongoose debug log to separate file

Tags: debugging, node.js, express, mongoose

I set the mongoose debug to true.

> mongoose.set('debug', true)

But now the debug log is printing in console.I need to specify a separate file for mongoose debug so that I can check the queries if needed.How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the great aaron heckmann answered this in [Logging outbound queries](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/aCMpWx587b4)

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (collectionName, method, query, doc [, options]) {

  //save to file what you need

});
```

Comment: how does mongoose format the log? IE I would like to use the second option to let winston log. I like the format mongoose logs and I would format my log w/ winston the same way.

Comment: it's not quite clear to me, what you're asking.. as for the above example you can use winston like this `var winston = require('winston');
mongoose.set('debug', function (collectionName, method, query, doc [, options]) {
winston.log('mongo', collectionName, arguments);
});`

Comment: mongoose.set('debug', true), produces nicely formatted output to console.  But I want to log that using winston and would like the same format mongoose uses but I cannot reproduce that format.  Got to be in the code somewhere/

Comment: have a look here, [debug code in source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js#L120-L201)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you would probably have to open a filehandle and write the error to that file.

But for a short-cut, what I do is capture all output of console and log it to a file when I start my app:

```
node app.js 1>$APP_DIR/log/app.log 2>&1 &
```

Then you can tail the log file:

```
tail -f ./log/app.log
```